# Сортировка

Tags: массивы, php, сортировка

Есть код:

```
$string = '524,525,481';
$string_array = explode(',', $string);

$q = $db->query("SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tfrom` = '2' ORDER BY `tid` DESC");
while($d = $db->fetch($q)) {
 echo $d['tid'].' ';
}
```

`echo $d['tid']` выводит:

> 529 525 524 486 481

И есть массив `$string_array`, в котором находятся значения. Как с помощью него, вывести цифры в таком порядке?

> 524 525 481 529 486

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = '524,525,481';
$string_array = explode(',', $string);

$q = $db->query("SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tfrom` = '2' AND `tid` NOT IN (".$string.") ORDER BY `tid` DESC");
while($d = $db->fetch($q)) {
 $string_array[] = $d['tid'];
}
print_r($string_array);
```

Comment: Вот это бред...

Comment: @ModaL - угу, но решение согласно вопросу...

Comment: все равно проголосовал "за". Но хотелось бы что-то лучше.

Comment: @ModaL, а куда лучше-то? К сортировке Ваш вопрос не имеет никакого отношения.

Второй возможный вариант - добавление условия в цикл вывода 

`if (!in_array($d["tid"], $string_array)) { echo $d["tid"]; }`

Еще вариант, который выдаст тот же результат:

`
$string = '524,525,481';
 
 $string_array = explode(',', $string);
 
 $string2 = '529,525,524,486,481';
 
 $string_array2 = explode(',', $string2);
 
 print_r(array_merge($string_array, array_diff($string_array2, $string_array)));`

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=(count($string_array)-1); $i>=0; $i--) 
{
   if(($key = array_search(array_pop($string_array[$i],$new_string_array))!== false) 
   {
      unset($new_string_array[$key]);
      array_unshift($new_string_array,$string_array[$i]);
   }
}
```